# MacOS Browsers Squish Content to Fit

Tags: css, reactjs, macos, material-ui, overflow

Something I've noticed in a bit of React development is that MacOS browsers attempt to cram all of the page content into view instead of simply allowing the user to scroll. For example:

```js
function Example()
{
    const Elements = (new Array(5)).fill(<div style={{backgroundColor: 'red', border: '1px solid', height: '100px', width: '100%'}} />)
    return (
        <div style={{
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'flex-start',
            overflow: 'auto',
            height: '500px',
            width: '100px',
        }}>
            {Elements}
        </div>
    )
}
```

displays fine on both MacOS and Windows. However, when you change `new Array(5)` to `new Array(50)`, only Windows browsers display as intended. All browsers on MacOS attempt to cram the 50 divs into the 500px container.

**If I set `min-height`, it will work.** However, this is exceptionally frustrating when using Material-UI components like `Collapse` or `ExpansionPanels` where the height is animated (or even just other components designed without `min-height` specified). Why do only MacOS browsers do this, and how do I fix/get around it without manually animating/setting `min-height`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I can't necessarily explain *why* MacOS browsers do this, but I figured out how to fix it. Setting `flex-shrink: 0` on the container (and sub-containers) that should scroll instead of compress seems to do the trick. I would love to know if this is a flexbox bug or a feature, or if I've been misunderstanding flexbox.